# SQL group by on mutiple columns - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+
| id | action   | object_type | object_id | created_at          | user_id | object_title              |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+
|  1 | shared   |           0 |         1 | 2016-04-22 06:13:16 |       1 | 5 highest buildings       |
|  2 | liked    |           0 |         1 | 2016-04-22 06:15:02 |       1 | 5 highest buildings       |
|  3 | liked    |           0 |         1 | 2016-05-21 19:02:18 |       2 | 5 highest buildings       |
|  4 | liked    |           1 |         3 | 2016-05-21 19:02:21 |       3 | 5 largest bridges         |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+
```

I'm trying to build some thing similar to Facebook's news feed. I mean when multiple users in my friend list like same post, we will show only single result in th news feed saying that friend1, friend2, frnd3, etc., like this xyz post.

From this table I would like to group by on these three columns (`action`, `object_type`, `object_id`) and a list of users for this object.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
GROUP BY action, object_type, object_id
```

But this gave me some weird results, and I was expecting a list of users. I' really don't have any clue how to do that in this query.

Any help or lead will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try this solution for :

`SELECT action, object_type, object_id, count(user_id) as user  FROM mytable 
GROUP BY action, object_type, object_id`

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and then show us the expected result!

Comment: use GROUP_CONCAT to get a list of grouped rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT action, object_title,count(user_id) as user_count, group_concat(user_id) as user_ids 
   FROM mytable GROUP BY action, object_type, object_id;
```

Comment: so this would return a count of users who made any action. right? how can I get those ids instead of count.?

Comment: Thanks ... I didn't know about `group_concat` at all. :)

Comment: Mahesh, one more thing, user_ids are foreign key to user table, instead of user_ids, is it possible to get their emailid/username in the same query? other wise i have to make 2 queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116067/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-wendy).